Why Is My OpenVPN so slow
I configured an OpenVPN server on a Windows Server. On the same computer (192.168.1.204) I have a Web Server that I'm trying to access remotely through the VPN. I have successfully accessed it remotely, but for some reason it takes minutes to load a single page. I was wondering what I'm doing wrong.
This is my server config
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
#tun-mtu 1200
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
keepalive 10 120
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
verb 3
explicit-exit-notify            
client-to-client
script-security 3
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.204"
push "route 192.168.1.204 255.255.255.255"
username-as-common-name
auth-user-pass-verify "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\check_credentials.bat" via-env
ca "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ca.crt"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.crt"
key "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\server.key"
dh "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\dh.pem"
tls-auth "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\config\\ta.key" 0

This is my client config
client
dev tun
proto udp
#tun-mtu 1200
remote <public-ip> 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
key-direction 1
auth-user-pass
verb 3

<ca>
</ca>

<cert>
</cert>

<key>
</key>

<tls-auth>
</tls-auth>


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What is the ISP plan upload speed? If that isn't the issue, the configs can be tuned for higher throughput (for example, see these). Also, tls-crypt should be used since TLS-Auth was depreciated years ago.
